# Makefile:7: *** missing separator. Stop (HELP NEEDED)

Tags: makefile

I am trying to make a Makefile but keep getting the "Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop" error & yes i did use tab instead of whitespaces .

My Makefile is below :

```
CC =gcc
CFLAGS = -I.
DEPS= prog3.h
OBJ= prog3.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

bucketsort: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Are there actual tab characters on the `$(CC)` lines? Your editor may have inserted spaces when you hit the tab key.